# Show just specific group of regexp and remove rest of the line in bash with sed

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I have an access log with many lines in the following format:

```
1.2.3.4:443  - - [11/Mar/2020:09:41:05 +0100] RESPONSE_CODE:[200] AGE: [-] CACHE_MISS: [-] CACHE-STATUS: [-] SIZE: [1288] RESPONSE_TIME: [2/2125012] (microseconds) WAS:[was.internal:9444] "PUT /kudosboards/node/a8740540-801a-43a6-822a-d58a2424fd3f HTTP/1.1" 200 REFERER: "https://ihs.internal/kudosboards/"
```

I just want to get the response time, so in this example `2/2125012`. My idea was to write a regex pattern, that matches the brackets content in a group, and everything after/before it in other groups. So I could replace the entire line by just this value:

```
^(.*)RESPONSE_TIME: \[([^\]]+)(.*)$
```

Using [101regex](https://regex101.com/) with an example input string, it gavae me `` as second group as expected:

```
Group 2 2/2125012
```

To use this pattern with `egrep`, I escaped the brackets like this:

```
$ sed 's#^\(.*\)RESPONSE_TIME: \[\([\^\]]+\)\(.*\)$#\2#g' testfile
1.2.3.4:443  - - [11/Mar/2020:09:41:05 +0100] RESPONSE_CODE:[200] AGE: [-] CACHE_MISS: [-] CACHE-STATUS: [-] SIZE: [1288] RESPONSE_TIME: [2/2125012] (microseconds) WAS:[was.internal:9444] "PUT /kudosboards/node/a8740540-801a-43a6-822a-d58a2424fd3f HTTP/1.1" 200 REFERER: "https://ihs.internal/kudosboards/"
```

Why is nothing replaced? I escaped `(` and `[`.

It seems that this has something to do with the square brackets:

```
$ sed 's#^\(.*\)RESPONSE_TIME: \[\(.*\)\] (micro\(.*\)$#\2#g' testfile
2/2125012
```

This worked. But those pattern is not very specific. I'd like make it more specific by having e.g. `[0-9]+/[0-9]+` for the pattern inside the brackets instead of `(.*)` *wildcard* pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern contains an issue related to the use of POSIX BRE/ERE: `[\^\]]+` matches a char that is either  `^` or `]` and then a `+` char ([demo](https://ideone.com/HiF8Ll)). You need to use `*` (that matches *0 or more occurrences*) instead of `+`, or `\+` in GNU `sed`, or `\{1,\}` in a generic POSIX BRE.

You may fix the `sed` command by using

```
sed -n 's#.*RESPONSE_TIME: \[\([^]]*\).*#\1#p' testfile
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/71PiTb).

**Details**

- `-n` -suppresses the default line output
- `.*RESPONSE_TIME: \[\([^]]*\).*` - matches any 0+ chars, `RESPONSE_TIME:`, space, `[`, then captures into Group 1 any zero or more chars other than `]`, and then matches the rest of the string
- `\1` - replaces the match with the Group 1 value
- `p` - prints the result of the substitution.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F'[][]' '{print $14}' file
2/2125012
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output including cases that the above doesn't work for.